# Unity - Apply Post-Processing Effects to all UI Elements

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, effects, post-processing

I have been learning to use Unity's **Post-Processing Effects** but I cannot work out how to apply these effects to any **UI Elements**. I would like to try and add a bloom effect and some colour correction to improve my game's sci-fi look. If anybody knows how to do this a reply would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Tommy

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Canvas then you can change **Render Mode** from **Screen Space-Overlay** to **Screen Space-Camera** and dragging your Camera with the **Post-Processing Effects** to **Render Camera** and then all effect should be visible on the UI too.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I have changed my render mode to Screen Space - Camera and my post processing effects are now working. However, by doing this my UI has become blurry for some reason. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is happening is probably a Post-Processing effect that is doing that. By doing what I said will apply all effects you have active. You can test by deactivating each effect one by one to find what is blurring it. One workaround is having a seperate "UI Camera" that only renders the UI with it own effects.

Comment: I have tried deactivating all effects but it is definitely down to switching the UI to Screen Space Overlay. Also it's all of my UI which I am applying the post processing effects so using a different camera would not work.

Answer (score 3):

Set the canvas Render Mode to Screen Space - Camera, then drag the camera into the Render Camera.

If you can't see the canvas then change the Plane Distance value, probably to something positive.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm incredibly late to this but I found the following steps to work great:

- setting the canvas to screen space camera
- changing the canvas's plane distance to 0.06
- changing the camera's near clipping planes to 0.01
- turning off any depth of field volume overrides
- setting the camera's anti-aliasing to anything but FXAA